# Unable to upload the Electron appx app to the MS app store

Tags: electron, windows-store, appx, msix

Bundle MSIX packages: I have created .msix package for windows App. I tried to submit in MS store, Please refer attachment for error:

[image]

As error mentioned, the existing uploaded package is in bundle format. and the package we created in .msix/appx format. Hence unable to upload this package to store.
We used the below reference to create the bundle. but no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/bundle-msix-packages

shows below error:

**`MakeAppx : error: Bundle creation failed.
MakeAppx : error: 0x8051100f - The specified package format is not valid: The zip archive is missing the end of central directory marker.`**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ([at Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-windows-package.html)) are working on dedicated support from bundles from Advanced Installer. If you are interested, email us at *support@advancedinstaller.com* and mention this thread, my colleagues can try to help you get this done.